# How to define a class as get set variable in another class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am trying to call a wrapper class which is written independently. I am trying to call the class as a get set variable in a apex class. But getting error while i try to define the class as get set variable. But if I try to call the same class inside the apex class method i am able to access remote wrapper class.

I want to use the class as object on VF page for form filling. We can use the wrapper class inside the main class.But I am trying this out if it is possible or not.

My wrapper class

```
public class Wrapper{
public String FirstName {get; set;}
public String MiddleName {get; set;}
public String LastName {get; set;}    
}
```

Apex class where I call the wrapper

```
public class myClass{
pubilc Wrapper wap1 {get; set;} // Getting error when defied like this 
public void myfun(){
    Wrapper wap = new Wrapper (); // Able to access class from here  
}
}
```

Error message

> Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'Wrapper'. at line 2 column 12

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are able to access `Wrapper` inside your method? I'm asking because my guess here would be that your class isn't compiled yet. Try compiling `Wrapper` first and then save `myClass`.

Comment: Yes I was able to access the wrapper class inside the apex method.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in access modifier. it should be Public instead of pubilc. Public Wrapper wap1 {get;set;}

Comment: ooo what a sill mistake i made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working in your case is the misspelling in **pubilc Wrapper wap1**, should be **public Wrapper wap1**. Worked for me.